# Load data from WebAPI to the ViewController

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, swift, api, swift3

My current code working perfectly, it is for data load from web api to the `UIViewController` (`UITableView`).
But I am confused that if it violates the Dependency Inversion Principle(DIP) of **SOLID**?
If so, how to fix that?

```
class AreaController: UIViewController {

        var townCityList : [TownCity]?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

           // locations implements ILocation interface

            let service = NetworkModelTownCity()


            // So here, when creating a new instance you're injecting the dependecy.

            let dataprocess = DataProcessLocation(location : service)


            dataprocess.locations({ (locations) in

                 self.townCityList = locations
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }
```

---

```
protocol Ilocation {

    func townCitys(_ completionHandler: @escaping (_ locations: [TownCity]) -> Void)
}
```

---

```
class DataProcessLocation {

    var location : Ilocation!

    init(location : Ilocation) {

       self.location = location
    }

    func locations(_ completionHandler: @escaping (_ locations: [TownCity]) -> Void) {

        self.location.townCitys( { (locations) in

            completionHandler(locations)

        })

    }


}
```

---

```
class NetworkModelTownCity : Ilocation {


     func townCitys(_ completionHandler: @escaping ([TownCity]) -> Void) {

        let _jsonFormatString = ["":""]

        RestApiService.shared.fetchDataByPostRequest(with: _jsonFormatString  , actionMethod: Constants.ApiRequest.actionMethod.townCity.rawValue) { (json) in

            var  _objs = [TownCity]()

            print(json)

            guard let objList = json as? [AnyObject] else {
                return
            }

            for obj in objList {
                if  let _obj = TownCity(fromAPIResponse: obj as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
                    _objs.append(_obj)
                }

            }


            completionHandler(_objs)

        }
    }

}
```

---

```
class TownCity{

    var  townId : String = ""
    var  cityId : String = ""
    var  townName : String = ""
    var selectedShopTypeId : String = ""

    init?(fromAPIResponse resposne : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>){

        guard let townId = resposne["townId"]  as? String , let cityId = resposne["cityId"] as? String , let townName = resposne["townName"] as? String  else {  
            return nil
        }

        self.townId = townId
        self.cityId = cityId
        self.townName = townName
    }
}
```

Comment: just some general comments: why override viewDidLoad if you are simply calling the superclass? doesn't make sense. also i would inject DataProcessLocation as a parameter when instantiating the areaController which means you won't have a need to instantiate NetworkModelTownCity in your controller.

Comment: Do any additional setup after loading the view for `override viewDidLoad` . apple `xcode swift boilerplate`  code

Comment: @t3chb0t `Load data from WebAPI to the ViewController` it is working fine no issue or problem but i need  concept SOLID (DIP)

Comment: Please do not change the title. The original one violates the site rules. It should tell what the code does and not be your quesiton about the code.

Comment: @t3chb0t could you explain please why you remove my problem .. if you provide this `Load data from WebAPI to the ViewController`  then no issue in my code

Comment: I didn't remove it. I just fixed the title. You mention your problem in the question here _but i am confuse is violates the Dependency Inversion Principle_. Now everything is fine.

Comment: If you are not sure about it then please take a moment and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58341/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-t3chb0t).

Comment: @BKSpurgeon could you make answer for me  with this part `i would inject DataProcessLocation as a parameter when instantiating the areaController which means you won't have a need to instantiate NetworkModelTownCity in your controller.`